# What user installs a .deb package?

Tags: users, dpkg

I am experiencing a behavior in the installation of a *.deb* package that I don't really understand.

I have a set of "things" in my computer that I deploy to remote computers using a *.deb* package. I work in my local machine logged as the user "`borrajax`". There's also a "`borrajax`" user in the remote machine where I install my *.deb*. When I need to deploy my "things", I create a *.deb* package in my machine (with `sudo dpkg --build`), copy it to the remote machine and install it with `sudo dpkg -i myPackage.deb` . When I do that, the "expanded" (or installed) files become owned by the local user `borrajax`, which is good.

Now, I have a coworker that also tries to do the same thing but he is logged in as a different local username (he doesn't have a `borrajax` user in his machine, but... `foobar` - I guess his parents didn't like him much-). He follows exactly the same process I do with my local user `borrajax` but with his local `foobar` user: Create the `.deb` in his machine, copy it to the remote machine and install it with `dpkg -i`. Well... In that case, the installed files become owned by `root`, which prevents the installation to continue (which is not a bug, but a feature).

All these machines are Ubuntu (11.10 mine, 12.04 the remote one and my coworker's one) so what I would like is the package become installed with whatever user has the uuid 1000. I would expect the name not to be so relevant (It may be just a coincidence there's a `borrajax` user in my machine and in the remote one).

So in this case, the username seems very relevant. Why is that? As I mentioned earlier, my local user `borrajax`, my coworker's `foobar` and the `borrajax` in the remote machine are all the uid=1000. Why does the user's name (seem to be) so important? My local `borrajax` user may not have anything to see at all with the `borrajax` in the remote machine. If the package was created by the user with uid 1000, why "sometimes" (if I've created it) it is installed with whatever user has the uid 1000 in the remote machine and "sometimes" it's installed with root (if my coworker has created it)?

I can always change the owner of the installed files using `chown 1000` in  the postint script, or use some other kind of workaround but I would like to understand first why is this happening, and how is it that the username in two different machines seems so important?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Show us the output of `ls -l path/to/file` in the package build tree, where `path/to/file` is one of the files that has the wrong ownership. Also show us the output of `dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile foo.deb | tar tvf -` on each machine.

Comment: Your question seems to be based on a flawed assumption and / or a local override for an important system default. `sudo dpkg -i` should always run as `root` and the installed files should be owned by `root` (except for `suid` scripts perhaps, and files belonging to a dedicated system account such as `www-data`).

Comment: If you intend to use a .deb package to deploy an app, you shouldn't assume that the end user will have id 1000 anyway. If it's just you and some friends who are getting the package then that's okay.